# Why was Elizabeth in the rain and alone?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

At the beginning of [Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_Dead_Man%27s_Chest), it shows Elizabeth Swann in the rain, by herself.

This happened before Cutler Beckett arrests Will and Elizabeth. And even before Beckett's arrival to the Port Royale.

It's supposed to be her wedding day. Just before her marriage why was she alone? And why she was kneeling under the rain?

It shows a number of chairs and wedding arrangements in the background.

Comment: I don't think I saw the movie, but if Will is still feeling like Elizabeth really had feelings for Jack, then it sounds like the scene is meant to show that it's not before their wedding, but that the wedding was called off.  Here as a comment because, again, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That scene depicts the wedding getting cancelled.

You might be confused because arrival of Cutler Beckett and arresting turner is shown in kind of flashback.

Basically, movie shows this scene like kind of prolouge.

So sequence of events are like this :

1. Cuttler Becket arrives.
2. He arrests Turner under charges for helping Jack.
3. Swan is crying ( this scene which was shown in start ).
4. Cuttler arrests Swan.

This scene is shown in start as it sets the mood of movie or emphasis on importance of their marriage.
This marriage is main motive for swan and turner to do Cuttler's bidding

Comment: I just rewatched this scene, and while this is the most logical explanation, the directors did a poor job conveying it. The flashes to Lord Beckett's men disembarking appears to be at the same time of day, in the same terrible rainstorm, as Elizabeth, sitting alone. The troop scenes progress to arresting Will and bringing him to Elizabeth, all which appears to be in real time.

Comment: Sure agree and its not kind of movie where we expect it , differnt audience. These kind of play fits in movies like Momento , Pulp fiction where audience is focused and ready for this stuff.